Pandas map two dataframe based on column name mentioned on the other df and partial match to derive new column
I have two dataframes df1 & df2 as below.
import pandas as pd


data1 = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3],
        'Column2': ['Account', 'Biscut', 'Super'],
        'Column3': ['Funny', 'Super', 'Nice']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'ColumnName':['Column2','Column3','Column1'],
     'ifExist':['Acc','Sup',3],
     'TarName':['Account_name','Super_name','Val_3']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

I want to add new column TarName to the df1 by partially matching the ifExists value from df2 against the ColumnName that Mentioned in the df2 with df1.
My Expected Ouput is:
Column1    column2     column3  TarName
1          Account     Funny    Account_Name
2          Biscut      Super    Super_name  
3          Super       Nice     Val_3

I have tried below code. This code able to partial map but only to one column. With this approach I Need to create dictionaries as many column mapping I have and need to apply as many.
Is there more dynamic approach ?
df2_Column2_dict = df2[df2['ColumnName']=='Column2'].set_index(['ifExist'])['TarName'].to_dict()
pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(df2_Column2_dict.keys()))
extracted = df1['Column2'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).dropna()
df1['TarName'] =  extracted.apply(lambda x: df2_Column2_dict[x]).reindex(df2.index)

print(df1)


What if you have more than one match in a row? For instance if your first row in df1 had Super in place of Funny?

@mozway when I have more than one match I need to give peference based on the ColumnName from df2. since the column2 comes first the expected output is Account_Name though the column3 matches

But if you take the third row, there are two matches: 3 and "Sup", both of which are in the correct column

@mozway But Sup lookup column should be Column3. I don't have mapping in the sup with ColumnName as Column2.

I would agree if the "ColumnName" was in the df1, it is in the df2 here, so do you mean that the index 0 in df1 should match index 0 in df2? If not, then please clarify/fix your example. Could you then have 3 rows in df1 and 4 in df2 (or the other way around) to ensure things are not ambiguous?

I hope help you with the code. For each concept/line is the explanation with a comment.
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrames
data1 = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3],
        'Column2': ['Account', 'Biscut', 'Super'],
        'Column3': ['Funny', 'Super', 'Nice']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'ColumnName':['Column2','Column3'],
        'ifExist':['Acc','Sup'],
        'TarName':['Account_name','Super_name']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Initialize new column in df1
df1['TarName'] = ''

# Iterate over each row in df2
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    # Column in df1 to search
    column_name = row['ColumnName']  
    
    # Partial value to search for
    if_exist = row['ifExist']        
    
    # Value to assign if there is a match
    tar_name = row['TarName']        

    # Find partial matches and assign TarName
    mask = df1[column_name].str.contains(if_exist, case=False, na=False)
    df1.loc[mask, 'TarName'] = tar_name

# Show the result
print(df1)

Edit: Tell if you need to solve it without loops

I just realised my data that I am using to compare if_exist contains some special charecters like -,  (' which is causing an error that error: missing ), unterminated subpattern'.

I have updated the mask expression as fallows. mask = df1[column_name].astype(str).str.contains(str(if_contains).replace("(", "\(").replace(")", "\)"), case=False, na=False).

Can you please share how to do without loops as well ?

It looks like df1 and df2 are aligned.
In this case you don't really need to search in all rows and you can restrict the search to the same position. In the end either you will map the TarName, or None if there is no match.
Thus you could simplify the code to use indexing lookup with validation of the substring:
idx, cols = pd.factorize(df2['ColumnName'])

vals = df1.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1)), idx]

df1['TarName'] = [t if str(i) in str(v) else None
                  for v, i, t in zip(vals, df2['ifExist'], df2['TarName'])]

Output:
   Column1  Column2 Column3       TarName
0        1  Account   Funny  Account_name
1        2   Biscut   Super    Super_name
2        3    Super    Nice         Val_3


Let me try this first

For me this code output  TarName as Super_name for the Index value 3 Instead of 'Val_3'.

@RoshanNuvvula I double-checked and it doesn't for me (pandas 2.2.2), did you try with your exact provided input. But can you please explain the logic to chose a column? Do you get the first available column?

To choose the Column. from df2 value in the ColumnName Needs to map to df1[ColumnName] then get the ifExist value from df2 and look for for partial match against the df1 of the column that we matched in the first step. If condition Satisfied need to add TarName from df2 to df1

@RoshanNuvvula I suspect your example is incorrect, you don't have a "ColumnName" in df1. Is this a mistake? If yes then it's a different logic and I will update the answer.

What I mean is as example df2["ColumnName"].iloc[1] is Column3. Now I need to look for column3 in df1 and the df2['ifExist'] is 'Sup' further I need to look for the 'sup' available in df1['column3'] or not. if there is a match then I need to update df1 with TarName as 'Super_name'. I Am not sure I convyed it correctly

So, if I follow you if df1 has n rows, df2 should also have n rows and there are matching one-on-one? This would change a lot the logic. Please confirm and I'll update my answer.

Yes. df2 contains the column names that have it in df1

@RoshanNuvvula Please check the update, if df1 and df2 are aligned as your comments strongly suggest then this should be the most efficient approach

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3],
         'Column2': ['Account', 'Biscut', 'Super'],
         'Column3': ['Funny', 'Super', 'Nice']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'ColumnName': ['Column2', 'Column3', 'Column1'],
         'ifExist': ['Acc', 'Sup', 3],
         'TarName': ['Account_name', 'Super_name', 'Val_3']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df1['TarName'] = pd.Series(np.nan* len(df1), dtype='object')

value_matches = [
df1[col].astype(str).str.contains(str(ifexist),case=False,na=False)    
for col, ifexist in zip(df2['ColumnName'],df2['ifExist'])    
]
masks= np.stack(value_matches)
print(masks)

# Apply the target names based on the masks
for i, tarname in enumerate(df2['TarName']):
        df1.loc[masks[:, i], 'TarName'] = tarname

print(df1)


"""
   Column1  Column2 Column3       TarName
0        1  Account   Funny  Account_name
1        2   Biscut   Super    Super_name
2        3    Super    Nice         Val_3
"""

